# Read data from OECD API into python (and pandas)

Tags: python, api, pandas

I'm trying to download data from OECD API (https://data.oecd.org/api/sdmx-json-documentation/) into python.

I managed to download data in SDMX-JSON format (and transform it to JSON) so far:

```
OECD_ROOT_URL = "http://stats.oecd.org/SDMX-JSON/data"

def make_OECD_request(dsname, dimensions, params = None, root_dir = OECD_ROOT_URL):
    """Make URL for the OECD API and return a response"""
    """4 dimensions: location, subject, measure, frequency"""

    if not params:
        params = {}

    dim_args = ['+'.join(d) for d in dimensions]
    dim_str = '.'.join(dim_args)

    url = root_dir + '/' + dsname + '/' + dim_str + '/all'

    print('Requesting URL ' + url)
    return rq.get(url = url, params = params)

response = make_OECD_request('MEI'
    , [['USA', 'CZE'], [], [], ['M']]
    , {'startTime': '2009-Q1', 'endTime': '2010-Q1'})


if (response.status_code == 200):
    json = response.json()
```

How can I transform the data set into pandas.DataFrame? I tried pandas.read_json() and pandasdmx library, but I was not able to solve this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Update:

The function to automatically download the data from OECD API is now available in my Python library CIF (abbreviation for the Composite Indicators Framework, installable via pip):

```
from cif import cif
data, subjects, measures = cif.createDataFrameFromOECD(countries = ['USA'], dsname = 'MEI', frequency = 'M')
```

## Original answer:

If you need your data in Pandas DataFrame format, it is IMHO better to send your request to OECD with additional parameter `'dimensionAtObservation': 'AllDimensions'`, which results in more comprehensive JSON file.

Use following functions to download the data:

```
import requests as rq
import pandas as pd
import re

OECD_ROOT_URL = "http://stats.oecd.org/SDMX-JSON/data"

def make_OECD_request(dsname, dimensions, params = None, root_dir = OECD_ROOT_URL):
    # Make URL for the OECD API and return a response
    # 4 dimensions: location, subject, measure, frequency
    # OECD API: https://data.oecd.org/api/sdmx-json-documentation/#d.en.330346

    if not params:
        params = {}

    dim_args = ['+'.join(d) for d in dimensions]
    dim_str = '.'.join(dim_args)

    url = root_dir + '/' + dsname + '/' + dim_str + '/all'

    print('Requesting URL ' + url)
    return rq.get(url = url, params = params)


def create_DataFrame_from_OECD(country = 'CZE', subject = [], measure = [], frequency = 'M',  startDate = None, endDate = None):     
    # Request data from OECD API and return pandas DataFrame

    # country: country code (max 1)
    # subject: list of subjects, empty list for all
    # measure: list of measures, empty list for all
    # frequency: 'M' for monthly and 'Q' for quarterly time series
    # startDate: date in YYYY-MM (2000-01) or YYYY-QQ (2000-Q1) format, None for all observations
    # endDate: date in YYYY-MM (2000-01) or YYYY-QQ (2000-Q1) format, None for all observations

    # Data download

    response = make_OECD_request('MEI'
                                 , [[country], subject, measure, [frequency]]
                                 , {'startTime': startDate, 'endTime': endDate, 'dimensionAtObservation': 'AllDimensions'})

    # Data transformation

    if (response.status_code == 200):

        responseJson = response.json()

        obsList = responseJson.get('dataSets')[0].get('observations')

        if (len(obsList) > 0):

            print('Data downloaded from %s' % response.url)

            timeList = [item for item in responseJson.get('structure').get('dimensions').get('observation') if item['id'] == 'TIME_PERIOD'][0]['values']
            subjectList = [item for item in responseJson.get('structure').get('dimensions').get('observation') if item['id'] == 'SUBJECT'][0]['values']
            measureList = [item for item in responseJson.get('structure').get('dimensions').get('observation') if item['id'] == 'MEASURE'][0]['values']

            obs = pd.DataFrame(obsList).transpose()
            obs.rename(columns = {0: 'series'}, inplace = True)
            obs['id'] = obs.index
            obs = obs[['id', 'series']]
            obs['dimensions'] = obs.apply(lambda x: re.findall('\d+', x['id']), axis = 1)
            obs['subject'] = obs.apply(lambda x: subjectList[int(x['dimensions'][1])]['id'], axis = 1)
            obs['measure'] = obs.apply(lambda x: measureList[int(x['dimensions'][2])]['id'], axis = 1)
            obs['time'] = obs.apply(lambda x: timeList[int(x['dimensions'][4])]['id'], axis = 1)
            obs['names'] = obs['subject'] + '_' + obs['measure']

            data = obs.pivot_table(index = 'time', columns = ['names'], values = 'series')

            return(data)

        else:

            print('Error: No available records, please change parameters')

    else:

        print('Error: %s' % response.status_code)
```

You can create requests like these:

```
data = create_DataFrame_from_OECD(country = 'CZE', subject = ['LOCOPCNO'])
data = create_DataFrame_from_OECD(country = 'USA', frequency = 'Q', startDate = '2009-Q1', endDate = '2010-Q1')
data = create_DataFrame_from_OECD(country = 'USA', frequency = 'M', startDate = '2009-01', endDate = '2010-12')
data = create_DataFrame_from_OECD(country = 'USA', frequency = 'M', subject = ['B6DBSI01'])
data = create_DataFrame_from_OECD(country = 'USA', frequency = 'Q', subject = ['B6DBSI01'])
```

Answer (score 10):

[The documentation the original question points to](https://data.oecd.org/api/sdmx-json-documentation/) does not (yet?) mention that the API accepts the parameter `contentType`, which may be set to `csv`. That makes it trivial to use with Pandas.

```py
import pandas as pd

def get_from_oecd(sdmx_query):
    return pd.read_csv(
        f"https://stats.oecd.org/SDMX-JSON/data/{sdmx_query}?contentType=csv"
    )

print(get_from_oecd("MEI_FIN/IRLT.AUS.M/OECD").head())
```

Comment: That's cool. I wonder whether this functionality has always been there? Because I still cannot find it in the documentation.

Comment: this just saved me a lot of headache 

Answer (score 2):

You can recover the data from the source using code like this.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

URL = 'http://stats.oecd.org/SDMX-JSON/data/MEI/USA+CZE...M/all'

response = urlopen(URL).read()
responseDict = json.loads(str(response)[2:-1])
print (responseDict.keys())
print (len(responseDict['dataSets']))
```

Here is the output from this code.

```
dict_keys(['header', 'structure', 'dataSets'])
1
```

If you are curious about the appearance of the `[2:-1]` (I would be) it's because for some reason unknown to me the **str** function leaves some extraneous characters at the beginning and end of the string when it converts the byte array passed to it. **json.loads** is documented to require a string as input.

This is the code I used to get to this point.

```
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen
>>> import json
>>> URL = 'http://stats.oecd.org/SDMX-JSON/data/MEI/USA+CZE...M/all'
>>> response = urlopen(URL).read()
>>> len(response)
9886387
>>> response[:50]
b'{"header":{"id":"1975590b-346a-47ee-8d99-6562ccc11'
>>> str(response[:50])
'b\'{"header":{"id":"1975590b-346a-47ee-8d99-6562ccc11\''
>>> str(response[-50:])
'b\'"uri":"http://www.oecd.org/contact/","text":""}]}}\''
```

I understand that this is not a complete solution as you must still crack into the **dataSets** structure for the data to put into pandas. It's a list but you could explore it starting with this sketch.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. However this is pretty much the same output I got when I used the function mentioned in the question. I added another answer which covers also the next step (loading the data into pandas DataFrame)

Answer (score 2):

The latest release of pandasdmx ([pandasdmx.readthedocs.io](http://pandasdmx.readthedocs.io)) fixes previous issues accessing OECD data in sdmx-json.

Comment: Can you please add some OECD example? I found only one for Eurostat.