# Download OECD API data using Python and SDMX

Tags: python, sdmx

I'm trying to execute the following SDMX query using Python from the OECD's database.

```
https://stats.oecd.org/restsdmx/sdmx.ashx/GetData/LAND_COVER_FUA/AUS+AUT.FOREST+GRSL+WETL+SHRUBL+SPARSE_VEGETATION+CROPL+URBAN+BARE+WATER.THOUSAND_SQKM+PCNT/all?startTime=1992&endTime=2019
```

I've looked around but can't get this to work with the existing packages and tutorials out there (I've looked at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40565871/read-data-from-oecd-api-into-python-and-pandas) for example).

Would you be able to help? I can't seem to get the various libraries (`pandasdmx`, `cif`, etc.) to work with it.

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`sdmx1`](https://sdmx1.readthedocs.io):

```py
import sdmx

OECD = sdmx.Client("OECD_JSON")
key = dict(
    COU="AUS AUT".split(),
    FUA=[],
    VARIABLE="FOREST GRSL WETL SHRUBL SPARSE_VEGETATION CROPL URBAN BARE WATER".split(),
    MEAS="THOUSAND_SQKM PCNT".split(),
)

# Assemble into a string
key_str = ".".join("+".join(values) for values in key.values())
print(f"{key_str = }")

# Commented: these keys are invalid
# key_str = "AUS+AUT.FOREST+GRSL+WETL+SHRUBL+SPARSE_VEGETATION+CROPL+URBAN+BARE+WATER.THOUSAND_SQKM+PCNT"
# key_str = "AUS+AUT.FOREST+GRSL+WETL+SHRUBL+SPARSE_VEGETATION+CROPL+URBAN+BARE+WATER.THOUSAND_SQKM+PCNT."

# Retrieve a data message
dm = OECD.data(
    "LAND_COVER_FUA",
    key=key_str,
    params=dict(startPeriod=1992, endPeriod=2019),
)

# Retrieve the first data set in the message
ds = dm.data[0]

# Convert to pandas
print(sdmx.to_pandas(ds))
```

This gives output like:

```
$ python q.py 
key_str = 'AUS+AUT..FOREST+GRSL+WETL+SHRUBL+SPARSE_VEGETATION+CROPL+URBAN+BARE+WATER.THOUSAND_SQKM+PCNT'

COU  FUA      VARIABLE  MEAS           TIME_PERIOD
AUS  AUS01    BARE      THOUSAND_SQKM  1992           0.000618
                                       2004           0.000618
                                       2015           0.000618
                                       2018           0.000541
                                       2019           0.000541
                                                        ...   
AUT  AT005L4  WATER     THOUSAND_SQKM  1992           0.001314
                                       2004           0.001314
                                       2015           0.001314
                                       2018           0.001314
                                       2019           0.002319
Name: value, Length: 2160, dtype: float64
```

A few key points to understand:

- The URL you give (with `/GetData/`) indicates an SDMX 2.0 API. These are very old and few tools support them.
- OECD provides both an SDMX-ML 2.1 and an SDMX-JSON API.

  - The package documentation above includes [some notes on these](https://sdmx1.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sources.html#oecd).
  - This particular data flow (`LAND_COVER_FUA`) does not appear to be available from the "OECD" (SDMX-ML) source, only from the "OECD_JSON" one.
  - The package can only automatically construct a key from a dict when SDMX-ML is available. Since we have to use the JSON endpoint, we manually construct the key.
- Parameters like "startTime=1992" are outdated/incorrect; the current form for SDMX 2.1 and later is "startPeriod=1992".
- Your key only has 3 parts, but this data flow has 4 dimensions. If you uncomment the first line above that sets `key_str` explicitly, the web service responds:

  > Semantic Error - Wrong number of non-time dimensions provided. Expected 4. Query contains 3

  If we randomly guess and put an extra period at the end (second commented `key_str`), we get the error:

  > Semantic Error - Dimension 'FUA' does not contain code(s) 'FOREST,GRSL,WETL,SHRUBL,SPARSE_VEGETATION,CROPL,URBAN,BARE,WATER'

  This indicates that (a) the missing dimension is the second one and (b) it has an id "FUA". So we insert this in `key`. Notice that the resulting, valid key string contains `+AUT..FOREST+`. These two consecutive periods (`..`) indicate "No specific labels/return all labels for this dimension."

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful reply, this is great--thanks again.